# Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

More of a discussion than anything, but we've got 15 unanswered questions, and I know as a forum site type user, the biggest turn off is when you post a question and get nothing in return.

Any suggestions for how we can give these a boost? Perhaps tweet them out once a day or something? I try to answer one from this list each day, but some of them I have no idea about, sadly.

Comment: I did what I could, which wasn't a lot but did include [letting bicycles.SE know](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/464/keirin-question-on-travel-stack-exchange-would-it-be-better-here) about [our old keirin question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/994/how-to-find-keirin-races-in-japan).

Comment: Kudos, we're down to 9 today!

Comment: Wheeeeeeee! \o/

Comment: And 4 now. Tricky almost open-ended ones a couple of them though...

Comment: It seems to work, I also just visited the unanswered tab, and we have only 7 questions unanswered! Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from periodic visits to the '[unanswered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered)' tab, the best way to get a question answered is to share it!

[image]

Use those social bookmark tools and seek out others in Facebook, email, or Tweet them as a challenge to get the question answered. Everyone likes a challenge and people really love to show off on occasion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To repeat what was mentioned by another but was subsequently deleted (by that other) put a bounty on them. That is, if they deserve a bounty.